# How do you determine the build options that XCode uses so you can use them with xcodebuild?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to build my iOS projects with xcodebuild, but to do so I need to figure out all the flags and options that XCode is using to build my project when I build and run in XCode.

How can I find out what compilation flags and such XCode is using during the build process, so that I can figure out the equivalent xcodebuild command? I'm especially interested in getting this to work when I'm including external libraries like RestKit in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is tell `xcodebuild` the target and the configuration; everything else is contained in the project relating to the configuration.

See the [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode3build.1.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was passing the wrong flags to xcodebuild but with your encouragement figures it out. What do you use to launch the stuff xcodebuild just built in the simulator from the command line?

Comment: @dan Sorry I don't know the answer to your second question.